# Error when deleting a node using Cypher in Memgraph

Tags: memgraphdb

When I try to delete the node

```
MATCH (c:Customer {name: 'John Smith'})
DELETE c;
```

I get the message `Failed to remove node because of it's existing connections. Consider using DETACH DELETE.`. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just follow the error message and replace `DELETE` with `DETACH DELETE`:

```
MATCH (c:Customer {name: 'John Smith'})
DETACH DELETE c;
```

`DELETE` can only be used on nodes that have no relationships. To delete a node along with all of its relationships, you need to add `DETACH`.